# Unable to successfully user Desktop Sharing

Tags: remote-desktop

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.10.0-37-generic x86_64) running on a machine that recently stopped allowing remote desktop connections. I originally followed this [tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/setup-ubuntu-remote-desktop-4129666) and things were working well and the only change that I made was changing my NVIDIA graphics driver, but now I am unable to log in via the IP address:port or server name:port.

The system is up to date and although I am able to SSH into the machine, I would like to also use a GUI every now and then. Would using another vnc server besides vino possibly be the best long-term solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have had good success with [x11vnc](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8984)

Comment: I tried x11vnc (and the script) with the same result. I have since changed the video driver back to the generic one with no success. Trying to restart vino this is the error that I am receiving:
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display:

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I went back to the Xorg based video driver, rebooted and the problem went away.

Comment: Was this the video driver on your remote system?  That's cool that you answered your own question.  You might want to add some more detail to how you fixed it so that others that might be experiencing the same issue can see what you did to fix it.  =)

Comment: @Terrance great point :-) . Updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I went back to the Xorg based video driver, rebooted and the problem went away.
Settings --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers --> X.Org X server (see screenshot) & reboot.

[Additional Drivers Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX3Pq.png)